# For every Stepfunction f exists a continuous function g with f=g a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a non-empty, finite interval and $A_k\subset I,\ k=1,...,M$ pairwise disjoint and measurable sets which compose $I$. Furthermore, let $f\colon I \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be of the form $f=\sum_{k=1}^M a_k\chi_{A_k}, a_k\in\mathbb{R}$.

I have to show that there is a continuous function $g$ with $f=g$ almost everywhere.

At this point I am unsure, whether this can be true. I understand that this could be possible, but not with this type of staircase function in general. For this, I somehow can not figure out how to create a continuous function $g$ out of $f$ just using the nullsets of $f$.

For instance, take

$f=\begin{cases}
    1, & \text{for } (-\infty,a] \\
    0, & \text{else}  
    \end{cases}$

where $a\in \mathbb{R}$. I could not make $f$ continuous using just nullsets of $f$, can I?

Comment: You are right. This is not possible.

Comment: Just to be sure: Originally, I should show that "For every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a continuous function $g$, such that $\lambda (\{x\in I:f(x)\ne g(x)\})<\varepsilon$." But this is the same as $f=g$ a.e., is that correct?

Comment: No, it's not the same. Note that $g$ may depend on $\epsilon$.

Comment: This is of course not the same. What you have to prove is true. It is known as blabla's theoerm, where I forgot who blabla was. ;-) EDIT: Ah, I think blabla = Lusin.